# Excel checkbox, When clicking copy cells and past to new sheet

Tags: excel

I want to click a checkbox, and then it copys the two cells beside it. then it have to check on a new sheet if the to first colums on the first row is free. if they are then past, if they are not then check if the next row i free and so on.

Im not so skilled so a step by step guide would be nice.

sorry my poor english. and thanks

[image: see picture of senario]

[image: Database and Keynote]

Greatings from
Jesper

Comment: have you tried to use the macro-recorder? it should give all you need... the only part you wont get, is the first empty cell/row... but there are tons of answers showing how to do that. so for the first step, start the macro recorder and copy the cells manually.

Comment: also... what do you think should happen if you uncheck the box?

Comment: If i uncheck a box it could remove the pasted cells and reorder the list on the other sheet, so there is no holes.

Comment: Im not sure i understand. if it is not to much i would like a step by step solution. i have loaded a new pic. where its a database that will be updated from time to time.

Comment: Didn't my solution fit your request? It does what you want and you don't need any VBA at all...

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a different non-vba approach:
Insert a "form control" checkbox for each line and connect it to a non used cell in that line (in my example column A)
Then simply get the values by formula (ive done it at 1 sheet, but te ranges simply can be changed)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C$16,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$16=TRUE,ROW($A$1:$A$16)),ROW())),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with ctrl + shift + enter!

[image]